# Javascript object comparision for each key and value

Tags: javascript-objects

```
var obj1 = {a:1, b:2, c:3};
var obj2 = {a:3, b:2, c:1};
```

How to compare the objects are equal or not using javascript (for loop).

I tried comparing both the objects by converting via stringify, but the comparison fails when the keys are misplaced or not in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

Go like this

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype,"equals", {
    value: function (array) {
        for ( key in this )
            if ( ! ( array[key] === this[key] ) )
                return false;
        for ( key in array )
            if ( ! ( array[key] === this[key] ) )
               return false;
       return true;
    }
});
```

which will add a `equals`-method to all objects. You can use it like this:

```
[0,1,2].equals([0,1,2]);       // true
[0,1,2].equals([0,1,3]);       // false
[0,1,2].equals([0,1,2,3]);     // false
obj1.equals(obj2);             // true
```

Note that this function doesn't compare in a sense of comparing "deep".